# Tramp with 2-factor authentication

Tags: tramp, ssh

I need to use Tramp to connect to a server that has 2-factor authentication.

When I log in from the command line or from  I get a message asking me to press 1 (and hit enter) which then sends a popup message to my phone asking me to approve the log in.

I can't figure out how to get Tramp to let me interact with the command prompt after it tries to connect. I get a buffer that says "Passcode or option (1-1):" but I can't figure out how to enter a value to have Tramp send back to the server.

Comment: That sounds really cool. How is the two-factor authentication done? I'm interested in setting up something myself.

Comment: I am using this: https://www.duosecurity.com/docs/duounix It works pretty well so far. It's free for the sort of small scale thing I have set up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to customize the `tramp-password-prompt-regexp` variable with the second prompt to finish the 2-factor authentication. The [remote shell setup](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Remote-shell-setup) part of the manual has a simple example.

This is not a new feature but an old feature that you adapt to the second prompt of the 2-factor authentication. This same facility was used in days of yore for entering some secret date or random number or mother's maiden name.

Comment: Man, I wish I was around during the days of yore.