# Tramp login with 2-factor authentication

Tags: tramp, ssh

To ssh, the server I am connecting to needs a password followed by an RSA-like key.

It goes:

```
Password:
Verification code:
```

I've read [Tramp with 2-factor authentication](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16581/tramp-with-2-factor-authentication), but it does not solve the problem completely.

I've appended "Verification code" into tramp-password-prompt-regexp.

But what happens when I try to login is that I get an opportunity to put in my password, and then I see:

```
Tramp: Sending Password
Tramp: Sending Verification code
Tramp: Sending Password
Tramp: Sending Verification code
Tramp: Sending Password
Tramp: Sending Verification code
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
```

Before it eventually fails. I feel like it's treating Verification code and Password as one and the same, and instead of prompting me for a Verification code, it just goes ahead and sends the password.

How do I get tramp to prompt a second time for the verification code? I want it to collect a second `read-string` from the user or something.

Comment: What happens, if you disable password caching? Let's say, try `(setq password-cache nil)`.

Comment: That was a good idea. I was able to enter in my verification code. I then got the following error however.

`unix_listener: "/var/folders/jy/__string__/T/tramp.__string__.__username@domain__:22.__string__" too long for Unix domain socket`

Comment: Yes, this is a known problem in Tramp reported as Emacs bugs 19702 and 21374. Solved (likely) in Emacs 24.5, solved for sure in Emacs 25.0.50 (the development version of Emacs).

Comment: I updated to 25.5.1 and I was able to login. Very cool feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution (per Michael Albinus, above) for 2-factor authentication in Tramp:

- upgrade Emacs to 24.5 or use Emacs development version 25.0.50 or later

[Also see related answer.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16584/7045)