# emacs tramp: how to input a password and additional verification?

Tags: tramp

When I manually login into remote server, it first needs to input password, and then input some youbikey like the following prompt.

```
Password:    (after I input password correctly, then it will show the next line.)
Tap your Key:
```

Then in tramp, after I input password correctly, it hangs there without any further info. How to make it work in tramp?

I am already using version 25.

So the following doesn't work for me.
[Tramp login with 2-factor authentication](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17573/tramp-login-with-2-factor-authentication)

Comment: Why doesn't work the solution you've referenced to? Could you show how it fails?

Comment: After I input the password, it should asked again for "tap your YubiKey", but it doesn't show that.  The reality is after I input the password, press Enter, but that press doesn't make any change.I expected it should show some other message to let me input more.

Comment: after I add "Tap your Key" to the variable of password-word-equivalents, now it works. thanks.  But still can't reuse an existing ssh connection from iterm2 (I have ask it in another question). I will close this now for now.

Answer (score 2):

In the file macs-plus/25.1/share/emacs/25.1/lisp/simple.el.gz
I added "Tap your Key" to  password-word-equivalents, then it works.

```
(defcustom password-word-equivalents
  '("password" "passcode" "passphrase" "pass phrase"
    ; These are sorted according to the GNU en_US locale.
    "암호"        ; ko
    "Tap your Key" ; for 2 factor
    "パスワード" ; ja
.....
```

Comment: In general, you shouldn't edit that file. Your changes will be overwritten next time you get a fresh emacs. It would be better to adapt `password-word-equivalents` in your .emacs.